# How can I give common calls from main controller

Tags: javascript, angular, daterangepicker

I am setting up date in all of the pages in my site and based on these calls API's shows - data. However I need to select date everytime I visit a new page from calender shown( i.e all pages/controllers are having individual calender set). But I want if once I have selected a date, it remains same throughout all pages I visit. I am having a call for

`$scope.cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());`

which is common across all of my pages, ie - every controller has this call. What should I add to my main controller or how can I pass input for the above call for all pages in my site.

Is this the right way ?!

Answer (score 0):

Here as per your need, you have to set the date and then use it across the pages.

For this purpose Angular has provided two ways:

**Way 1:**
`$rootScope`: This is the parent scope of the all the $scope in Angular. So if you set anything over it, it will be presented everywhere.

```
// way to set the date
$rootScope.selectedDate = // your date object;

// way to fetch the date
var date = $rootScope.selectedDate
```

**Way 2:**
Service: Angular is provided `Service` concept which are the singleton object. Means once you set anything over it, will be available wherever you want.

**Creating Service:**

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
.service('commonService', function() {
    var selectedDate;

    this.setDate = function(date) {
      selectedDate = date;
    }

    this.getDate = function() {
      return selectedDate;
    }

});
```

**How to use it:**

```
angular.module('someModule')
.controller('someCntrl', function($scope, commonService) {
  // way to set the date
  var date = //some date;
  commonService.setDate(date);    

})
.controller('otherCtrl', function($scope, commonService) {

  // way to fetch date
  var date = commonService.getDate();

});
```